# Detect long touch

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I need to detect long touch in the game the game I am trying to make.How can I do so?
Other problem I am facing is to limit simultaneous touches. i.e the sprite won't jump if user touches more than two times immedeatly one after other.
Also is their a way by which I can add touch duration factor to the height of jump the sprite makes?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how do you grab your touches? I always use the following methods:

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touchx withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touchx withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

And in these methods you may take total control over all touches. For example remember the time the touch started:

```
self.startTime = [NSDate date];
```

for an instance variable startTime, or to check if a touch belongs to a certain object:

```
 CGRectContainsPoint(self.rect, [self convertTouchToNodeSpaceAR:touch]);
```

This way you can easily implement your touch logic the way you like it...

A good way to do this is - I find - to define all the required variables within the object of the game, like...

```
@interface Enemy : CCSprite <CCTargetedTouchDelegate> {

    EnemyState state;
    NSInteger enemyID;
    NSDate *startTime;
    NSDate *endTime;

    UITouch *lastTouch;
```

ADDED TO SHOW CONCRETE EXAMPLE CODE FOR ccTouchBegan:

```
   - (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        D_DBG (@"ENEMY ID %i",self.enemyID);

//implement your logic if a touch for this enemy is allowed or not
        if (![self.delegate touchIsAllowed: enemyID touch: touch]) return NO;

//if the enemy is untouched, then may be touched
        if ((state == kEnemyStateUngrabbed) &&  (![self containsTouchLocation:touch] )) return NO;

        state = kEnemyStateGrabbed;
        self.startTime = [NSDate date];
        [self.delegate  informAboutEnemyStarted: self.enemyID startTime: self.startTime atPoint: self.position];
    return YES;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.But how startTime signifies start of touch?

Comment: In - (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
you find the object which was touched and then there set it's variable startTime. Same at the end in - (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touchx withEvent:(UIEvent *)event. You just have to dispatch every touch yourself and check which object was meant. But that's almost automatically done if you use these methods...
--> dont forget to   [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:theEnemy priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];, so theEnemy can swall the touches where theEnemy is an instance of Enemy

Comment: Thanks.I got what you said.Let me implement the above.